# Bootstrap different height squares

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do the square setup from the image below.
The setup would be something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
                 <div class="color_red col-md-6">Heyyy</div>
                 <div class="color_blue col-md-3">hi</div>
         </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="offset-md-3 color_blue col-md-3">hi</div>
                 <div class="upped color_red col-md-6">Heyyy</div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

how would I go about setting `div` heights without using `fixed` height. I've read that this can be acchieved by using `padding-bottom:100%`, but I couldn't reproduce it. Any ideas?
[image: bootstrap four squares]

Comment: Not using 2 rows....you'd probably need at least 3 and 4 columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not using CSS grid:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "a a s ." 
  "a a b b" 
  ". p b b";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,70px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,70px);
  grid-gap:1px;
}

.big {
  background: red;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}

.small {
  background: blue;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}

.s {
  grid-area: s;
}

.p {
  grid-area: p;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
}
```

```html
<div class="big a">
hey am big
</div>
<div class="big b">
hey am big
</div>
<div class="small s">
hi
</div>
<div class="small p">
hi
</div>
```

Comment: No full support of `grid` by now, as I know, right?

Comment: @Heidel no it's pretty full supported ;) https://caniuse.com/#search=grid even with IE, you have to use some prefixes

Comment: I've heard about some problem in IE and Opera Mobile.

Comment: @Heidel but who care about IE ? :)

Comment: Not me, but I have heard it happens ;) By the way, where can I find information about prefixes for IE?

Comment: @Heidel here is a good article where you can also find other links : https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/

Comment: Not what I'm looking for.